# How to override a method in unit tests that is called from which the class being tested

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, easymock

I am testing a class A's function func1.

Func1 has a local variable of Class B and calls B's function func2. Code looks something like this:

```
public Class A
{
    public func1()
    {
       B object = new B();
       int x = object.func2(something);
    }
}
```

When I am testing func1 in its unit tests, I don't want func2 to get called.

So I am trying to do something like this in the test:

```
B textObject = new B()
{
   @override
   int func2(something)
   {
      return 5;
   }
}
```

But it is still calling the func2 in the class B. Please suggest how to handle this.

Comment: Could you use dependency injection, refactoring `A` to take `B` as an argument rather than creating a `new` one within the function? With such an abstract example it's hard to give sensible advice.

Comment: I can't really take B as an input in A's constructor neither in the func1 as an input because I am overriding func1 in the class A.
I can make B as a class variable in A but that doesn't seem to help either. What would you suggest in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is; again, the example is too abstract. Do some research around DI.

Comment: Solved this using dependency injection, thanks for the help.

Comment: in that case you can write up and accept your own answer, rather accepting one that isn't actually how you solved the problem!

Comment: What you are writing doesn't make sense. What does "I am overriding func1 in class A" to do with the arguments that you provide in the constructor of that class. The point is: if your code depends on external objects, and you want to change the behavior of those external objects, then you need a way to "inject" those objects into your class under test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to override the `new B()` constructor call - place it in an own method.

```
public Class A
{

    public func1()
    {
       B object = newB();
       int x = object.func2(something);
    }

    protected B newB(){
        return new B();
    }
}
```

In your test you can then override the `B` constructor call.

```
public class APartitialMock extends A {

   protected B newB(){
      return new BMock();
   }
}

public class BMock extends B {

    int func2(something) {
        return 5
    }

}
```

Then use `APartitialMock` to test the `func1` with your kind of `B`.

**PS** If you can or want to use a framework take a look at powermock - [Mock Constructor](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

Comment: I ended up solving this throw dependency injection, but this is great advise! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I can make B as a class variable in A but that doesn't seem to help
>   either. What would you suggest in this case?

If you make B as a class variable, then you can mock B, and "swap" it in the tested object of A.
Maybe not very elegant, but quick and simple.
An example:

```
public class B {
    int func2(int something){
        return 3*something;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class A
{
    // declare it as protected - a test need to have access to this field to replace it
    protected B object = new B();

    public int func1()
    {
       int x = object.func2(22);
       return x;
    }
}
```

---

And a test:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        A myA = new A();
        B myB = mock(B.class);

        // dummy function
        when(myB.func2(anyInt())).thenReturn(20);

        // replace B with mocked B
        myA.object = myB;

        int actual = myA.func1();

        assertEquals(20, actual);
    }
}
```