# Mockito mock not working on main method java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

```
public class example
{
    public void method()
    {
        System.out.println("Shouldn't be here!");
    }
}
```

```
public class examplemain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        example obj = new example();
        obj.method();
        System.out.println("Inside Main");
    }
}
```

I want to test *main* only and do not want to call *method* function.
I used this-

```
class examplemainTest
{
    @Test
    void main()
    {
        example obj = mock(example.class);
        doNothing().when(obj).method();

        String[] args = new String[0];
        examplemain.main(args); //line 1

        obj.method(); //line 2
    }
}
```

But still it is calling *method* function in line 1 and it is only working for line 2.
Following is the output I got after running the test.

Shouldn't be here!

Inside Main

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: that service is a local variable in your main method, so it's (obviously) not replaced by the mock. 
your main method should call your application, it shouldn't contain it.

extract it from there before starting with unit testing

Comment: PowerMockito.whenNew(example.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(your_mock_obj);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched a little bit, best way to handle testing of such kind of classes is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235373/how-to-override-a-method-in-unit-tests-that-is-called-from-which-the-class-being)

Answer (score 1):

The `obj` variable in `examplemain.main()` and `examplemainTest.main()` refer to different objects. In `examplemain.main()` you call method on the concrete object that you created on the previous line. In `examplemainTest.main()` you call the method on the mocked object you created in the beginning of the method.

You seem have trouble understanding some of the most fundamental concepts in Java programming. You should spend more time studying object initialization, object references, static access, field visibility and scope before diving into the fairly advanced topic of mocking dependencies in unit tests.

Comment: Thank you for answer, actually this is my first time writing unit testing.

Comment: Can you pleaase provide some insight on how should I do this test on main method.

Comment: The need to test main method is a sign of bad code. Main method should not contain testable logic. It should at most contain an invocation to a dynamically allocated class that implements the logic to be tested.