# PowerMockito whenNew thenReturn not working

Tags: unit-testing, powermockito

I have two classes like given below:

```
public class example
{
    public void method()
    {
        System.out.println("Shouldn't be here!");
    }
}
```

```
public class lol
{
    public void yes()
    {
        example obj = new example();
        obj.method();
    }
}
```

Following is the test I used

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({example.class,lol.class})
class examplemainTest
{
    @Test
    void yes() throws Exception
    {
        example obj = PowerMockito.mock(example.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(example.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(obj);

        //PowerMockito.whenNew(example.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(obj);

        obj.method();

        example aa = new example();
        aa.method();  //line 1

        lol bb = new lol();
        bb.yes();   //line 2
    }
}
```

line 1 and 2 still calling the original `lol::method()`.
Please, help me out, I don't know what am I missing, doing tests for the first time.
I also tried `whenNew().withNoArguments()` so I put it in the comments just so you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched a little bit, here `whenNew` does not mock the the methods but the constructor of the class provided (`example.class`). So if you define a constructor inside `example.class`that will be replaced by the constructor of your mock class but `example::method()` invoked here is the original one.
So now the question is how do we handle this situation, well I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235373/how-to-override-a-method-in-unit-tests-that-is-called-from-which-the-class-being) take a look.